# mongodb golang check collection exists

Tags: mongodb, go

I need to check if a collection exists.

I have created the following function:

```
func ExitsCollection(name string) bool {

    var exists bool = false

    names, err := cliente.CollectionNames()
    if err != nil {
        log.Println("[-]I cannot retrieve the list of collections")
    }

    // Simply search in the names
    for _, name := range names {
        if name == name {
            log.Printf("[+]The collection already exists!")
            exists = true
            break
        }
    }

    if !exists {
        log.Println("[+] The collection does not exist")
    }

    return exists
}
```

In order to connect I use the next function:

```
func ConectaBD() {

    cliente_local, err := mongo.NewClient(options.Client().ApplyURI(cadena_conexion))
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }

    ctx, cancelar = context.WithTimeout(context.Background(), 10*time.Second)
    err = cliente_local.Connect(ctx)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
    defer cancelar()

    mongo_cliente = cliente_local.Database(DATABASE)

    log.Println("[+]Connected to MongoDB Atlas")

}
```

I use the following variables:

```
var cliente_local *mongo.Client
var mongo_cliente *mongo.Database
var coleccion *mongo.Collection
var ctx context.Context
var cancelar context.CancelFunc
```

The problem is the next sentence:

***names, err := cliente.CollectionNames()***

What type of data or How do I can use the method CollectionNames()?

Does anyone have a sample source code?

Thanks in advance

===========================================

thank you all for your help!!!
I have created another question for session management:

[how i get a session in mongodb with golang](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70505598/how-i-get-a-session-in-mongodb-with-golang)

Comment: `if name == name` - this will always be true

Comment: "What type of data or How do I can use the method CollectionNames()?" - what does the documentation say about what this method returns?

Comment: func (db *Database) CollectionNames() (names []string, err error) Repository: github.com/go-mgo/mgo

Comment: You're not using mgo, though. (judging from your usage of `mongo.Client`, `mongo.Database` and others)

Comment: RE: "The problem is the next sentence:" What, exactly, is the problem? If it's an error, it should be included verbatim in the question. Please read the help center documentation on asking, especially on [how to ask good questions](//stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Database.CollectionNames()` returns the collection names present in the db database. The return type is `slice` so you need to check if your collection is listed or not.

Please check the official docs : https://pkg.go.dev/gopkg.in/mgo.v2#Database.CollectionNames

```
sess := ... // obtain session
db := sess.DB("") // Get db, use db name if not given in connection url

names, err := db.CollectionNames()
if err != nil {
    // Handle error
    log.Printf("Failed to get coll names: %v", err)
    return
}

// Simply search in the names slice, e.g.
for _, name := range names {
    if name == "collectionToCheck" {
        log.Printf("The collection exists!")
        break
    }
}
```

For better understanding refer this link : [How to check if collection exists or not MongoDB Golang](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46293070/how-to-check-if-collection-exists-or-not-mongodb-golang)

Comment: I have never created a session in mongodb, How could I get it? Thanks

Comment: please refer this link : https://www.agiratech.com/learn-golang-mongodb-tutorial-examples but i would say please use latest driver.