# how i get a session in mongodb with golang

Tags: mongodb, go, session, mongo-go

I need to use the method **CollectionNames()** in order to list all the collections of a database.

I will have to create a **session** in mongoDB:

```
sess := ... // obtain session
db := sess.DB("") // Get db, use db name if not given in connection url

names, err := db.CollectionNames()
```

Where could I find a example to get a session in MongoDB?

I have always connected with the DB of the next way:

```
cliente_local, err := mongo.NewClient(options.Client().ApplyURI(cadena_conexion))
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }

    ctx, cancelar = context.WithTimeout(context.Background(), 10*time.Second)
    err = cliente_local.Connect(ctx)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
    defer cancelar()

    mongo_cliente = cliente_local.Database(DATABASE)
```

How could I create a session?

Thanks in advance!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You seem to be confusing / mixing different MongoDB drivers. The `DB.CollectionNames()` exists in the `mgo` driver which is old and unmaintained.

The driver you use is the official `mongo-go` driver, which has a different method for obtaining the list of existing collections.

The `mongo-go` driver has the [`Database.ListCollectionNames()`](https://pkg.go.dev/go.mongodb.org/mongo-driver/mongo#Database.ListCollectionNames) method, you may use it like this:

```
names, err := mongo_cliente.ListCollectionNames(ctx, bson.D{})
// names is a []string holding all the existing collection names
```

Comment: Thank you so much!!! You are right. I didn't know the method "ListCollectionNames". Thank you icza!